# How can I force Postgres to return a reasonable row count without locking an entire table?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, count, heroku-postgres

We have recently moved a large application and database to Heroku from EngineYard. Our new database has less resources than the one on EngineYard, and has exposed some queries that probably only worked before due to big iron.

One particularly nasty problem is our inability to return counts from a large table. This table is the largest in the app and contains in excess of 1 billion rows. Some customers will have rows in the tens of thousands, while some may have one hundred million.

The table is indexed by a `subscription_id` and a `status`.

The query is simple:

```
select count(*)
from my_large_table
where subscription_id = 123
  and status = 'Valid'
```

Unfortunately this query appears to do an `ExclusiveLock` on the table, causing requests to queue up. For a customer with 5 million lines of data, the query must be killed after churning for an hour. This query is literally bringing our application to a halt.

However, we need to know the counts in that table for each customer and status. It doesn't have to be dead on. But it can't be a complete fiction like the `count_estimate` procedure which really just appears to report fictional numbers.

I am certain that there is a solution for this. What can I do to get this count? Is there some way to keep it from locking?

The table is huge and has tons of attributes. I went overboard on the `citext` values back when I designed it because I was coming over from MySQL where I was used to case-insensitive searches and had taken them for granted. I really only need `citext` on probably 4 columns tops (attribute1, attribute2). Those are really the names of the fields and not obfuscations. The table is a target for different types of data, based on the value of the `standard_id`.

I appreciate the help.

```
/*
 Navicat PostgreSQL Data Transfer

 Source Server         : Heroku myapp-production
 Source Server Version : 100600
 Source Host           : ec2-34-196-135-106.compute-1.amazonaws.com
 Source Database       : d6hrvd8r3u28t0
 Source Schema         : public

 Target Server Version : 100600
 File Encoding         : utf-8

 Date: 02/20/2019 09:37:49 AM
*/

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for apps
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."apps";
CREATE TABLE "public"."apps" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('apps_id_seq'::regclass),
    "attribute1" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute2" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute3" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute4" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute5" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute6" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute7" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute8" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute9" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute10" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute11" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute12" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute13" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute14" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute15" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute16" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute17" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute18" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute19" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute20" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute21" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute22" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute23" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute24" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute25" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute26" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute27" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute28" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute29" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute30" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute31" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute32" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute33" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute34" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute35" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute36" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute37" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute38" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute39" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute40" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute41" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute42" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute43" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute44" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute45" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute46" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute47" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute48" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute49" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "attribute50" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "created_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
    "standard_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "status" "public"."citext" COLLATE "default",
    "listing_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "repository_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "subscription_id" int4 NOT NULL,
    "attribute_info" "public"."hstore",
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "public"."apps" OWNER TO "ufn67drbuner1e";

-- ----------------------------
--  Primary key structure for table apps
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."apps" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

-- ----------------------------
--  Indexes structure for table apps
-- ----------------------------
CREATE INDEX  "app_listing_idx" ON "public"."apps" USING btree(listing_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "app_subscription_idx" ON "public"."apps" USING btree(subscription_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  "apps_listing_idx" ON "public"."apps" USING btree(listing_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, "id" "pg_catalog"."int8_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "apps_repository_idx" ON "public"."apps" USING btree(repository_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, subscription_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "listing_and_attr_idx" ON "public"."apps" USING btree(listing_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute1 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute2 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute3 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "listing_and_attr_idx" ON "public"."apps" USING btree(listing_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute1 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute2 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute3 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
CREATE INDEX  "listing_and_attr_idx" ON "public"."apps" USING btree(listing_id "pg_catalog"."int4_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute1 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute2 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST, attribute3 COLLATE "default" "public"."citext_ops" ASC NULLS LAST);
```

Comment: That query most definitely does not cause an ExclusiveLock. Read-only queries only create a very weak lock that prevents altering or dropping the table, but that's it. And readers never block other queries, there must be something else going on.  Can you actually see blocked sessions e.g. in `pg_stat_activity`? For one billion rows, this might indeed take some time, but it definitely does not "lock" the whole table. Maybe Heroku limits the number of sessions you can have and/or it limits the I/O or the number of concurrent queries.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** - if that never finishes, at least the output of a "simple" `explain`  [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). What is your exact Postgres version?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about [this `count_estimate()`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Count_estimate), it's just scraping the figures out of the `EXPLAIN` output, so it's limited by the granularity of the [planner stats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html). This'll work pretty well for a low-selectivity column like `status`, but you'd need an absurdly high [stats target](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET) to get anything even remotely useful for a user ID.

Answer (score 1):

About the lock: it is not caused by the `SELECT` query you are running.

The only explanation I have is that it is running in a transaction that has done something else that caused an `EXCLUSIVE LOCK` to be taken.

The only good theory is an `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` Than has run in the same transaction. Other things like relation extension locks (not held for the duration of the transaction) or `ALTER TYPE ... ADD VALUE` (which only blocks other such statements) don't look like likely suspects.

I don't know what nastinesses Heroku has built into their PostgreSQL, but I bet it was no `EXCLUSIVE LOCK` on `SELECT`.

But even without that spurious lock counting the number of rows in a table is slow and resource intensive.

If the usual estimates (`pg_stat_get_live_tuples()` and `pg_class.reltuples`) are not good enough, you can use a trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE row_counter (
   reloid oid PRIMARY KEY,
   count bigint NOT NULL
);

CREATE FUNCTION count_trig() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
      UPDATE row_counter
      SET count = count + 1
      WHERE reloid = TG_RELID;

      RETURN NEW;
   ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
      UPDATE row_counter
      SET count = count - 1
      WHERE reloid = TG_RELID;

      RETURN OLD;
   END IF;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER count_trig AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON my_large_table
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE count_trig();
```

You just have to initialize the table at some point.

A statement level trigger for `TRUNCATE` is left as exercise for the reader.

Comment: They're looking for a count per `subscription_id`, so the table-level tuple counts won't be much help...

Comment: Worth noting that the trigger-based approach means your inserts now need to contend for row locks, which can devolve into deadlock hell under certain write patterns. If you can live with slightly stale data, you might be much better off periodically recalculating counts from some background job.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. I had looked at a similar solution but indeed I'm looking for a count of the subset of the rows. Nick I have been considering that background job. My problem with that is that we're at 1,000 customers now, and these queries are taking too long to complete in a 24 hours period. I wonder if I just selected all of them and grouped by the subscription_id and status. I'll try it.

Comment: You can modify my answer so thathet

Comment: You can modify my answer so that the "count" table is grouped by `subscription_id` and `status` and the trigger updates the correct row. Should be a small modification.